# Twitter share option disables scrolling

Tags: ios

Im using the `SLviewcontroller` Class for sharing stuff on twitter from a view that contains a `UIScrollview` object. Everything works fine but when I tap the twitter button, either it cancels or sends tweet and return to the scrollview, and the scrollview does not scroll anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use:

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of dismissing with self, dismiss your twitter controller by itself.

Comment: ok thanks i actually figured it out. I was missing this two lines of code: [tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        }];